# Azure - IISConfigurator.exe has stopped working

Tags: sdk, azure

I've installed Windows Azure SDK for .NET June 2012 and when I try to run a project with a web role locally, I get the following error message:

"IISConfigurator.exe has stopped working"

In the event viewer I've found the following message:

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: iisconfigurator.exe
P2: 1.7.0.0
P3: 4fcaabb8
P4: System.Management
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 4ca2baf0
P7: 32f
P8: 12b
P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P10:

Attached files:
C:\Users\gert.vanmeerbergen\AppData\Local\Temp\WERB2EA.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\gert.vanmeerbergen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_iisconfigurator._26305d6c2cb0448de956b81b6cbdbc2cdc9158f9_2000b8e3

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: aeff36bf-cf0f-11e1-b2df-74de2b9a4969

I've already tried to re-installing the Windows Azure SDK but that doesn't help.

An idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Gert

Answer (score 13):

For reasons unknown installing the IIS Management Console fixed this problem for me.

I found this post: http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2012/07/iisconfiguratorexe.html, but I didn't need to install "Internet Infromation Services Hostable Web Core", only the management console.

I'm running w8

[image]

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 and encountered the same problem. I had already installed other IIS components but was missing the Management Console. Installing Management Console resolved my issue. I've encountered also some other Azure/Visual Studio issues that get fixed when you install IIS.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue when trying to run an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application with a Web Role. Quick fix for me was to right click VS and select run as administrator. Doing this let me then run in Google Chrome or any of the other browsers installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not directly related with Windows Azure in any way, and the only way you can link this is because it shows up with IISConfigurator.exe.

What you can do is create a new admin user in your machine and see if you still see the problem with new user, I think the problem should not exhibit with new user.

Based on above crash report your best bet is to clean all of user specific files, cache etc (cleaning appdata\local*) and then reboot the machine. This should fix your problem.